# How to display the nib filename associated with a specific class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can I output the nib file name of an object from a - **(void)awakeFromNib** method or from a given instance ?

I would like to know which is the associated nib to a given class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIViewController` has the [`nibName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName) property to do what you want. It'll return the name of the NIB file used to load it.